# Getters and setters to classes in Common Lisp

Tags: oop, lisp, common-lisp, setter, clos

I often have a class that is composed of a list of another class. For example, I'll have a vector-list class made up of vectors. To avoid writing long statements, I write a method to access the embedded class. However, this method only acts as a getter; I cannot use it to set the slot value. Is there a way to use a method to set a class slot value?

Below is a minimal example:

```
(defclass vector ()
  ((name :accessor vector-name
         :initarg :name)))

(defclass vector-list ()
  ((vectors :accessor vector-list-vectors
            :initarg :vectors)))

(defun make-vector-list ()
  (make-instance 'vector-list
    :vectors (list
               (make-instance 'vector :name 'v1)
               (make-instance 'vector :name 'v2))))

(defmethod access-vector-name ((vt vector-list) vector-idx)
  (vector-name (nth vector-idx (vector-list-vectors vt))))


;; returns V1
(print (access-vector-name (make-vector-list) 0))

;; Now, trying to set the same slot returns an error
;; How can I set the slot?
(setf (access-vector-name (make-vector-list) 0) 'new); --> error
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest would be to write:

```
(setf (aref (access-vector-name ...) index) value)`
```

But if you don't want to expose the fact that you have arrays/vectors, you can define a custom setf expander.

First, only define `access-vector-name` as a `:reader` in your class.
Then:

```
(defun (setf access-vector-name) (newval obj index)
  (setf (aref (access-vector-name obj) index) newval))
```

If the intent is to hide the underlying implementation, maybe `access-vector-name` is a bad name.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to define a setter method to do this.  However your code is not legal as it stands: `VECTOR` is a defined symbol in the `CL` package (and in fact names both a function and a type) so defining a class called `VECTOR` is horribly illegal (and a decent implementation would barf at this).  Here is a version of your code with the basic class renamed to `VEC`, and with a setter method.

```
(defclass vec ()
  ;; Don't call it VECTOR since it's a function in CL
  ((name :accessor vec-name
         :initarg :name)))

(defclass vec-list ()
  ((vecs :accessor vec-list-vecs
         :initarg :vecs)))

(defun make-vec-list ()
  (make-instance 'vec-list
    :vecs (list
           (make-instance 'vec :name 'v1)
           (make-instance 'vec :name 'v2))))

(defmethod access-vec-name ((vt vec-list) vec-idx)
  (vec-name (nth vec-idx (vec-list-vecs vt))))

(defmethod (setf access-vec-name) (new (vt vec-list) vec-idx)
  (setf (vec-name (nth vec-idx (vec-list-vecs vt))) new))
```

CLOS doesn't have a predefined macro to define accessor methods like this, outside class definitions: I'm not sure why but perhaps because cases where it's really a 'pure' accessor like this are relatively uncommon.

Comment: Well, you could name a class VECTOR if it the symbol belongs to another package... but that's nitpicking